# PBS job submission exeeds available cores

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, job-scheduling, pbs, torque

Here is the problem with Torque/PBS job manager. I ran the following command to allocate 8 cores on a node, however, I myself know that node has less than 8 idle cores. As you can see, the interactive job started means that everything is normal!

```
mahmood@cluster:~$ qsub -X -I -l nodes=compute-0-1:ppn=8
qsub: waiting for job 1488.cluster.edu to start
qsub: job 1488.cluster.edu ready
```

However, on another terminal, the output of `qstat -an` shows that it actually allocated 4 cores

```
1488.cluster.edu     mahmood     default  STDIN              5648     4      4    --    --  R   -- compute-0-3/31+compute-0-3/30+compute-0-3/29+compute-0-3/28
```

Also, `showq` command shows that only 4 cores were allocated

```
1488                mahmood    Running     4 99:23:53:55  Sat Dec 10 20:34:10
```

Maybe this seems to be normal and the PBS intelligently, allocates the remanding cores. However, when the user submits an 8-core job, 8 processes are created on the node. That means, the PBS allocated 4 cores but the job is running on 8 cores.

Since the node hadn't 8 idle cores, such situation shows that the CPU utilization is less than 100% because some cores are running multiple processes.

Any thought on that?s

Comment: Which version of torque is that? Seems like it completely ignores your specification `-l nodes=compute-0-1:ppn=8` and instead allocated four cores on `compute-0-3` node. Probably 4 cores is the default for the queue.

Comment: According to the qmgr command that queue has `resources_default.nodes=4`. Do you mean this?